# Relation between intensity at a point from a line source of sound and distance from the point

Tags: acoustics

I've read that the intensity of sound due to a *line source* at a distance **r** from the line source is *inversely proportional* to **r**. I really don't understand why does this proportionality differ with the size of the source(a point source, and a line source). Can someone provide me with a detailed proof of this occurence due to a *line source of sound*?(I'm a 12th grade student!)

Comment: Do you mean an infinite line source? Can you show the source of this information?

Comment: If it's a spherically symmetric emitter, the intensity decreases $\propto r^{-2}$.  If the source is an infinite line, the intensity decreases $\propto r^{-1}$.  The reason is related to geometry through something called [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law).